# Import globals from `d.ts` file using types instead of typings

Tags: typescript, typescript2.0

I have the following index.d.ts file for jasmine:

```
// Type definitions for Jasmine 2.2
// Project: http://jasmine.github.io/
// Definitions by: Boris Yankov <https://github.com/borisyankov/>, Theodore Brown <https://github.com/theodorejb>, David Pärsson <https://github.com/davidparsson/>
// Definitions: https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped


// For ddescribe / iit use : https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/karma-jasmine/karma-jasmine.d.ts

declare function describe(description: string, specDefinitions: () => void): void;
declare function fdescribe(description: string, specDefinitions: () => void): void;
declare function xdescribe(description: string, specDefinitions: () => void): void;

declare function it(expectation: string, assertion?: (done: DoneFn) => void, timeout?: number): void;
declare function fit(expectation: string, assertion?: (done: DoneFn) => void, timeout?: number): void;
declare function xit(expectation: string, assertion?: (done: DoneFn) => void, timeout?: number): void;

/** If you call the function pending anywhere in the spec body, no matter the expectations, the spec will be marked pending. */
declare function pending(reason?: string): void;

declare function beforeEach(action: (done: DoneFn) => void, timeout?: number): void;
declare function afterEach(action: (done: DoneFn) => void, timeout?: number): void;

declare function beforeAll(action: (done: DoneFn) => void, timeout?: number): void;
declare function afterAll(action: (done: DoneFn) => void, timeout?: number): void;

declare function expect(spy: Function): jasmine.Matchers;
declare function expect(actual: any): jasmine.Matchers;

declare function fail(e?: any): void;
/** Action method that should be called when the async work is complete */
interface DoneFn extends Function {
    (): void;

    /** fails the spec and indicates that it has completed. If the message is an Error, Error.message is used */
    fail: (message?: Error|string) => void;
}

declare function spyOn(object: any, method: string): jasmine.Spy;

declare function runs(asyncMethod: Function): void;
declare function waitsFor(latchMethod: () => boolean, failureMessage?: string, timeout?: number): void;
declare function waits(timeout?: number): void;

declare namespace jasmine {

    var clock: () => Clock;

    function any(aclass: any): Any;
    function anything(): Any;
    function arrayContaining(sample: any[]): ArrayContaining;
    function objectContaining(sample: any): ObjectContaining;
    function createSpy(name: string, originalFn?: Function): Spy;
    function createSpyObj(baseName: string, methodNames: any[]): any;
    function createSpyObj<T>(baseName: string, methodNames: any[]): T;
    function pp(value: any): string;
    function getEnv(): Env;
    function addCustomEqualityTester(equalityTester: CustomEqualityTester): void;
    function addMatchers(matchers: CustomMatcherFactories): void;
    function stringMatching(str: string): Any;
    function stringMatching(str: RegExp): Any;

    interface Any {

        new (expectedClass: any): any;

        jasmineMatches(other: any): boolean;
        jasmineToString(): string;
    }

    // taken from TypeScript lib.core.es6.d.ts, applicable to CustomMatchers.contains()
    interface ArrayLike<T> {
        length: number;
        [n: number]: T;
    }

    interface ArrayContaining {
        new (sample: any[]): any;

        asymmetricMatch(other: any): boolean;
        jasmineToString(): string;
    }

    interface ObjectContaining {
        new (sample: any): any;

        jasmineMatches(other: any, mismatchKeys: any[], mismatchValues: any[]): boolean;
        jasmineToString(): string;
    }

    interface Block {

        new (env: Env, func: SpecFunction, spec: Spec): any;

        execute(onComplete: () => void): void;
    }

    interface WaitsBlock extends Block {
        new (env: Env, timeout: number, spec: Spec): any;
    }

    interface WaitsForBlock extends Block {
        new (env: Env, timeout: number, latchFunction: SpecFunction, message: string, spec: Spec): any;
    }

    interface Clock {
        install(): void;
        uninstall(): void;
        /** Calls to any registered callback are triggered when the clock is ticked forward via the jasmine.clock().tick function, which takes a number of milliseconds. */
        tick(ms: number): void;
        mockDate(date?: Date): void;
    }

    interface CustomEqualityTester {
        (first: any, second: any): boolean;
    }

    interface CustomMatcher {
        compare<T>(actual: T, expected: T): CustomMatcherResult;
        compare(actual: any, expected: any): CustomMatcherResult;
    }

    interface CustomMatcherFactory {
        (util: MatchersUtil, customEqualityTesters: Array<CustomEqualityTester>): CustomMatcher;
    }

    interface CustomMatcherFactories {
        [index: string]: CustomMatcherFactory;
    }

    interface CustomMatcherResult {
        pass: boolean;
        message?: string;
    }

    interface MatchersUtil {
        equals(a: any, b: any, customTesters?: Array<CustomEqualityTester>): boolean;
        contains<T>(haystack: ArrayLike<T> | string, needle: any, customTesters?: Array<CustomEqualityTester>): boolean;
        buildFailureMessage(matcherName: string, isNot: boolean, actual: any, ...expected: Array<any>): string;
    }

    interface Env {
        setTimeout: any;
        clearTimeout: void;
        setInterval: any;
        clearInterval: void;
        updateInterval: number;

        currentSpec: Spec;

        matchersClass: Matchers;

        version(): any;
        versionString(): string;
        nextSpecId(): number;
        addReporter(reporter: Reporter): void;
        execute(): void;
        describe(description: string, specDefinitions: () => void): Suite;
        // ddescribe(description: string, specDefinitions: () => void): Suite; Not a part of jasmine. Angular team adds these
        beforeEach(beforeEachFunction: () => void): void;
        beforeAll(beforeAllFunction: () => void): void;
        currentRunner(): Runner;
        afterEach(afterEachFunction: () => void): void;
        afterAll(afterAllFunction: () => void): void;
        xdescribe(desc: string, specDefinitions: () => void): XSuite;
        it(description: string, func: () => void): Spec;
        // iit(description: string, func: () => void): Spec; Not a part of jasmine. Angular team adds these
        xit(desc: string, func: () => void): XSpec;
        compareRegExps_(a: RegExp, b: RegExp, mismatchKeys: string[], mismatchValues: string[]): boolean;
        compareObjects_(a: any, b: any, mismatchKeys: string[], mismatchValues: string[]): boolean;
        equals_(a: any, b: any, mismatchKeys: string[], mismatchValues: string[]): boolean;
        contains_(haystack: any, needle: any): boolean;
        addCustomEqualityTester(equalityTester: CustomEqualityTester): void;
        addMatchers(matchers: CustomMatcherFactories): void;
        specFilter(spec: Spec): boolean;
        throwOnExpectationFailure(value: boolean): void;
    }

    interface FakeTimer {

        new (): any;

        reset(): void;
        tick(millis: number): void;
        runFunctionsWithinRange(oldMillis: number, nowMillis: number): void;
        scheduleFunction(timeoutKey: any, funcToCall: () => void, millis: number, recurring: boolean): void;
    }

    interface HtmlReporter {
        new (): any;
    }

    interface HtmlSpecFilter {
        new (): any;
    }

    interface Result {
        type: string;
    }

    interface NestedResults extends Result {
        description: string;

        totalCount: number;
        passedCount: number;
        failedCount: number;

        skipped: boolean;

        rollupCounts(result: NestedResults): void;
        log(values: any): void;
        getItems(): Result[];
        addResult(result: Result): void;
        passed(): boolean;
    }

    interface MessageResult extends Result  {
        values: any;
        trace: Trace;
    }

    interface ExpectationResult extends Result  {
        matcherName: string;
        passed(): boolean;
        expected: any;
        actual: any;
        message: string;
        trace: Trace;
    }

    interface Trace {
        name: string;
        message: string;
        stack: any;
    }

    interface PrettyPrinter {

        new (): any;

        format(value: any): void;
        iterateObject(obj: any, fn: (property: string, isGetter: boolean) => void): void;
        emitScalar(value: any): void;
        emitString(value: string): void;
        emitArray(array: any[]): void;
        emitObject(obj: any): void;
        append(value: any): void;
    }

    interface StringPrettyPrinter extends PrettyPrinter {
    }

    interface Queue {

        new (env: any): any;

        env: Env;
        ensured: boolean[];
        blocks: Block[];
        running: boolean;
        index: number;
        offset: number;
        abort: boolean;

        addBefore(block: Block, ensure?: boolean): void;
        add(block: any, ensure?: boolean): void;
        insertNext(block: any, ensure?: boolean): void;
        start(onComplete?: () => void): void;
        isRunning(): boolean;
        next_(): void;
        results(): NestedResults;
    }

    interface Matchers {

        new (env: Env, actual: any, spec: Env, isNot?: boolean): any;

        env: Env;
        actual: any;
        spec: Env;
        isNot?: boolean;
        message(): any;

        toBe(expected: any, expectationFailOutput?: any): boolean;
        toEqual(expected: any, expectationFailOutput?: any): boolean;
        toMatch(expected: string | RegExp, expectationFailOutput?: any): boolean;
        toBeDefined(expectationFailOutput?: any): boolean;
        toBeUndefined(expectationFailOutput?: any): boolean;
        toBeNull(expectationFailOutput?: any): boolean;
        toBeNaN(): boolean;
        toBeTruthy(expectationFailOutput?: any): boolean;
        toBeFalsy(expectationFailOutput?: any): boolean;
        toHaveBeenCalled(): boolean;
        toHaveBeenCalledWith(...params: any[]): boolean;
        toHaveBeenCalledTimes(expected: number): boolean;
        toContain(expected: any, expectationFailOutput?: any): boolean;
        toBeLessThan(expected: number, expectationFailOutput?: any): boolean;
        toBeGreaterThan(expected: number, expectationFailOutput?: any): boolean;
        toBeCloseTo(expected: number, precision?: any, expectationFailOutput?: any): boolean;
        toThrow(expected?: any): boolean;
        toThrowError(message?: string | RegExp): boolean;
        toThrowError(expected?: new (...args: any[]) => Error, message?: string | RegExp): boolean;
        not: Matchers;

        Any: Any;
    }

    interface Reporter {
        reportRunnerStarting(runner: Runner): void;
        reportRunnerResults(runner: Runner): void;
        reportSuiteResults(suite: Suite): void;
        reportSpecStarting(spec: Spec): void;
        reportSpecResults(spec: Spec): void;
        log(str: string): void;
    }

    interface MultiReporter extends Reporter {
        addReporter(reporter: Reporter): void;
    }

    interface Runner {

        new (env: Env): any;

        execute(): void;
        beforeEach(beforeEachFunction: SpecFunction): void;
        afterEach(afterEachFunction: SpecFunction): void;
        beforeAll(beforeAllFunction: SpecFunction): void;
        afterAll(afterAllFunction: SpecFunction): void;
        finishCallback(): void;
        addSuite(suite: Suite): void;
        add(block: Block): void;
        specs(): Spec[];
        suites(): Suite[];
        topLevelSuites(): Suite[];
        results(): NestedResults;
    }

    interface SpecFunction {
        (spec?: Spec): void;
    }

    interface SuiteOrSpec {
        id: number;
        env: Env;
        description: string;
        queue: Queue;
    }

    interface Spec extends SuiteOrSpec {

        new (env: Env, suite: Suite, description: string): any;

        suite: Suite;

        afterCallbacks: SpecFunction[];
        spies_: Spy[];

        results_: NestedResults;
        matchersClass: Matchers;

        getFullName(): string;
        results(): NestedResults;
        log(arguments: any): any;
        runs(func: SpecFunction): Spec;
        addToQueue(block: Block): void;
        addMatcherResult(result: Result): void;
        expect(actual: any): any;
        waits(timeout: number): Spec;
        waitsFor(latchFunction: SpecFunction, timeoutMessage?: string, timeout?: number): Spec;
        fail(e?: any): void;
        getMatchersClass_(): Matchers;
        addMatchers(matchersPrototype: CustomMatcherFactories): void;
        finishCallback(): void;
        finish(onComplete?: () => void): void;
        after(doAfter: SpecFunction): void;
        execute(onComplete?: () => void): any;
        addBeforesAndAftersToQueue(): void;
        explodes(): void;
        spyOn(obj: any, methodName: string, ignoreMethodDoesntExist: boolean): Spy;
        removeAllSpies(): void;
    }

    interface XSpec {
        id: number;
        runs(): void;
    }

    interface Suite extends SuiteOrSpec {

        new (env: Env, description: string, specDefinitions: () => void, parentSuite: Suite): any;

        parentSuite: Suite;

        getFullName(): string;
        finish(onComplete?: () => void): void;
        beforeEach(beforeEachFunction: SpecFunction): void;
        afterEach(afterEachFunction: SpecFunction): void;
        beforeAll(beforeAllFunction: SpecFunction): void;
        afterAll(afterAllFunction: SpecFunction): void;
        results(): NestedResults;
        add(suiteOrSpec: SuiteOrSpec): void;
        specs(): Spec[];
        suites(): Suite[];
        children(): any[];
        execute(onComplete?: () => void): void;
    }

    interface XSuite {
        execute(): void;
    }

    interface Spy {
        (...params: any[]): any;

        identity: string;
        and: SpyAnd;
        calls: Calls;
        mostRecentCall: { args: any[]; };
        argsForCall: any[];
        wasCalled: boolean;
    }

    interface SpyAnd {
        /** By chaining the spy with and.callThrough, the spy will still track all calls to it but in addition it will delegate to the actual implementation. */
        callThrough(): Spy;
        /** By chaining the spy with and.returnValue, all calls to the function will return a specific value. */
        returnValue(val: any): Spy;
        /** By chaining the spy with and.returnValues, all calls to the function will return specific values in order until it reaches the end of the return values list. */
        returnValues(...values: any[]): Spy;
        /** By chaining the spy with and.callFake, all calls to the spy will delegate to the supplied function. */
        callFake(fn: Function): Spy;
        /** By chaining the spy with and.throwError, all calls to the spy will throw the specified value. */
        throwError(msg: string): Spy;
        /** When a calling strategy is used for a spy, the original stubbing behavior can be returned at any time with and.stub. */
        stub(): Spy;
    }

    interface Calls {
        /** By chaining the spy with calls.any(), will return false if the spy has not been called at all, and then true once at least one call happens. **/
        any(): boolean;
        /** By chaining the spy with calls.count(), will return the number of times the spy was called **/
        count(): number;
        /** By chaining the spy with calls.argsFor(), will return the arguments passed to call number index **/
        argsFor(index: number): any[];
        /** By chaining the spy with calls.allArgs(), will return the arguments to all calls **/
        allArgs(): any[];
        /** By chaining the spy with calls.all(), will return the context (the this) and arguments passed all calls **/
        all(): CallInfo[];
        /** By chaining the spy with calls.mostRecent(), will return the context (the this) and arguments for the most recent call **/
        mostRecent(): CallInfo;
        /** By chaining the spy with calls.first(), will return the context (the this) and arguments for the first call **/
        first(): CallInfo;
        /** By chaining the spy with calls.reset(), will clears all tracking for a spy **/
        reset(): void;
    }

    interface CallInfo {
        /** The context (the this) for the call */
        object: any;
        /** All arguments passed to the call */
        args: any[];
        /** The return value of the call */
        returnValue: any;
    }

    interface Util {
        inherit(childClass: Function, parentClass: Function): any;
        formatException(e: any): any;
        htmlEscape(str: string): string;
        argsToArray(args: any): any;
        extend(destination: any, source: any): any;
    }

    interface JsApiReporter extends Reporter {

        started: boolean;
        finished: boolean;
        result: any;
        messages: any;

        new (): any;

        suites(): Suite[];
        summarize_(suiteOrSpec: SuiteOrSpec): any;
        results(): any;
        resultsForSpec(specId: any): any;
        log(str: any): any;
        resultsForSpecs(specIds: any): any;
        summarizeResult_(result: any): any;
    }

    interface Jasmine {
        Spec: Spec;
        clock: Clock;
        util: Util;
    }

    export var HtmlReporter: HtmlReporter;
    export var HtmlSpecFilter: HtmlSpecFilter;
    export var DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL: number;
}
```

Please note that it uses `delcare namespace` and global `declare function` statements. Which means that this `d.ts` file were mend to be referenced via `/// <reference path="..." />` statement.

Now I'm using new bright and shiny **Angular 2** together with **TypeScript 2.0** application where I don't want to use old typings, instead I would like to use new `@types` approach. I.e. instead of referencing `d.ts` files with `/// <reference path="..." />` statement, I would like to use `import` statements however such approach does not play well with globals declared in `jasmine.d.ts`.

So how do I import individual global declarations declared in jasmine's `d.ts` file, taking into account that I can only comply it, i.e. I can't change real jasmine code which is written in JS.

Here is my sample test:

```
/// <reference path="../@types/jasmine/index.d.ts" />

import { By }           from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { TestBed }      from '@angular/core/testing';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

////////  SPECS  /////////////

/// Delete this
describe('Smoke test', () => {
  it('should run a passing test', () => {
    expect(true).toEqual(true, 'should pass');
  });
});

describe('AppComponent with TCB', function () {
  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({declarations: [AppComponent]});
  });

  it('should instantiate component', () => {
    let fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
    expect(fixture.componentInstance instanceof AppComponent).toBe(true, 'should create AppComponent');
  });

  it('should have expected <h1> text', () => {
    let fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
    fixture.detectChanges();

    let h1 = fixture.debugElement.query(el => el.name === 'h1').nativeElement;  // it works

        h1 = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('h1')).nativeElement;            // preferred

    expect(h1.innerText).toMatch(/angular 2 app/i, '<h1> should say something about "Angular 2 App"');
  });
});
```

So is there a way to get rid of `/// <reference path="../@types/jasmine/index.d.ts" />` and import jasmine's `d.ts` global declarations (such as `it`, `describe`, `expect`) using `import` statements approach from `typescript 2.0`

Answer (score 1):

> So is there a way to get rid of ///

You don't need reference tags if the files are included in your compilation context e.g. using `include` in your tsconfig.json https://basarat.gitbooks.io/alm/content/config/tsconfig.html